# Phonegap IOS plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I need a plugin for phonegap that would make it possible to view the video with GPS coordinates and icons layered on top of the video. Sort of like AR. so when turning and moving around you'll pass the GPS coordinate once you're looking in its direction.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue correctly this is a classic AR with an embed video between the reality background and the markers. As far as I know there is no phonegap plugin at the moment that covers your specific needs, you can see a list of existing phonegap plugins here: [github phonegap plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins). How ever you can make your own plugin for your purpose. I would take a look to http://www.layar.com/ and consider embedding it as a project library. See also if the pricing fits with your project.

Another approach could be to get rid of the plugin and just process the GPS and accelerometer information on your own, but the data processing looks quite more complex.